# Firebase open rate of push notifications shows no data

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I am sending Push Notifications on my iOS application from Firebase console and the notifications are delivered however the Notification section in Firebase does not show Open Rate(Mean how many notifications were open out of total sent ). Why is that happening ?

Comment: are you using FCM along with GCM??

Comment: Have you figured this out? I am having the same issue, I think it may be related to conflicting analytics libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I think gcm is not related here, he said he is working with ios, not android. I am experiencing the same behaviour with my iOS app here!